# Gremlin.compile() cannot execute query that works in gremlin console

Tags: gremlin, titan

When I execute the following in a gremlin console I get the expected result.

```
g.V('name', 'a').next().query().has('b', GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, 100).orderBy('timestamp', Order.DESC).edges()
```

Now I am trying to execute the same from Java (following [this](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java) guide) however I cannot get it to work.

I've tried this

```
Pipe pipe = Gremlin.compile("_().query().has('b', GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, 100).orderBy('timestamp', Order.DESC).edges()");
pipe.setStarts(new SingleIterator<Vertex>(graph.getVertices("name", 'a').iterator().next()));
for(Object name : pipe) {

}
```

> javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.GremlinGroovyPipeline.query() is
>   applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
>   every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure), grep(),
>   tree([Lcom.tinkerpop.pipes.PipeFunction;),
>   tree([Lgroovy.lang.Closure;),
>   tree(com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.structures.Tree)

And this

```
Pipe pipe = Gremlin.compile("_().next().query().has('b', GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, 100).orderBy('timestamp', Order.DESC).edges()");
pipe.setStarts(new SingleIterator<Vertex>(graph.getVertices("name", 'a').iterator().next()));
for(Object name : pipe) {

}
```

> javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.query()
>   is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
>   every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object),
>   any(), dump()

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks suspicious to me:

```
Pipe pipe = Gremlin.compile("_().next().query().has('b', GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, 100).orderBy('timestamp', Order.DESC).edges()");
```

You are trying to compile a `Pipe` out of something that doesn't evaluate to a `Pipeline`.  In other words, you start with the identity pipe (`_()`) but then you next() it out and drop down into a vertex query which returns `edges()`  `edges()` returns a `Iterator` and not a `Pipeline`.  If you look at the example of `Gremlin.compile` the evaluated code of the Gremlin string returns a pipeline.

```
Pipe pipe = Gremlin.compile("_().out('knows').name");
```

My guess is that if you instead changed your code to something like (untested):

```
Pipe pipe = Gremlin.compile("_().outE.has('b', GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, 100).order{it.b.timestamp <=> it.a.timestamp}");
pipe.setStarts(new SingleIterator<Vertex>(graph.getVertices("name", 'a').iterator().next()));
for(Object name : pipe) {

}
```

you might have some success.  I suppose that if that worked, then you would want to figure out how to re-optimize your query as I guess that some backends could take optimize the `orderBy` of the Vertex query, whereas the `order` Gremlin step is just an in-memory sort.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have decided to use GremlinGroovyScriptEngine instead of Gremlin.compile(). This approach is also described on the same [guide](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java) and I actually prefer this because it gives me parameterisation and I don't need to modify the original query (replace g. with _()).

```
ScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine();

Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
bindings.put("g", graph);
bindings.put("value", 100); 
bindings.put("DESC", Order.DESC);

engine.eval("g.V('name', 'a').next().query().has('b', Compare.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, value).orderBy('timestamp', DESC).edges()", bindings);
```

I would still be interested in knowing why Gremlin.compile did not work, hopefully the above will be helpful to someone else.